# Removing second/unity/nautilus bar behind gnome 3 top bar

Tags: 11.10, gnome, titlebar

When applying themes that have transparency set on the top bar (gnome shell/gnome 3), there is a unity or nautilus bar behind it that makes everything look like a mess.
That bar contains menu items like : file edit, about, help
Once i did the help button, when gnome 3 didn't start properly (so i was able to access this menu), and it said "Nautilus". I've seen that ppl around the net have this problem but does anyone here have a solution?

Comment: What kind of graphic card do you have ? And whether do you use proprietary driver or not ?
For me, it works great if I use radeon free driver (ATI card M86), but looks like a mess with the proprietary one.
More especially, the symptoms are : I've the bar bug but a lot of graphic artefact too.
For the moment I'm waiting for the new ATI fglrx driver to see if it will fix the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with gnome3-shell (top taskbar)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73482/problem-with-gnome3-shell-top-taskbar)

Comment: Why is this closed? It is very valid, loads of people are having this issue..

Answer (score 6):

This is because nautilus is handling the desktop You can disable it using gnome tweak tool if you dont have it it's

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

to install it

Then just turn "have file manager handle desktop" off as shown here

[image]

Comment: this solution isn't really handy is it... cuz i won't have my desktop anymore

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem myself, and after looking around I solved it. Fire up Synaptic and remove "appmenu-gtk" and "appmenu-gtk3" Log out or reboot and the menu should be gone. You aren't using Unity so you don't need them anyways.

Comment: Tried it not working :)

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a nautilus bar. If you kill nautilus processes, it goes away, but it comes back as soon as you start a "Files" activity. I have the same thing on my machine, but it's on my secondary monitor rather than behind my Gnome 3 bar. I've no idea how to get rid of it, unfortunately. I'm guessing it's related to the unified menu deal from Unity...

Comment: I even tried downgrading nautilus to the previous version (lucid lynx) but it has too many dependencies ... I like this gnome 3 and it could be powerful, if just it had no bugs...